# re-rendering issue using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Learning React Hooks, I am developing a testing app. My app loads data from an API and then populates a grid. Piece of kake. The problem shows up when I try to show a loading indicator. It enters in a re-render loop. Here is what I did:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComp(props) {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
   const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(!loading);

      const getData = response => {
         if (response.response) {
            setInfo(response.response);
         } else {
            console.log('there was an error');
         }
         setLoading(!loading);
      };

      fetch(URL, {})
        .then(resp => ({ getData({response: resp}))
        .catch(error => ({ getData({ error });
   }, []);

   return (
     <>
        {loading ? "Loading" : "Not Loading"}
     </>
   );
}

export default MyComp;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try using the callback type for a setState call to make it synchronous like this, `setLoading(oldState => !oldState)`.

Comment: @MananJoshi Since when passing a callback to `setState` makes it synchronous  ?

Comment: First i don't see any re-render loop can you explain what you mean further ? maybe put up a working code snippet illustrating the issue, Also Why you have a function declaration `getData` inside the `useEffect` seems inefficient ? The only issue i see is when updating your state based on the previous state you should use functional updates [Ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)  to ensure the next update makes use of the previous change, Right now both  `setLoading` are called using the previous state which `false` so it stays true

Comment: @ZohirSalak You are right, after a reebot it yells me that `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some "try and error" (I have to admit) I found this solution:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComp(props) {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
   const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(false);
   }, [info]);

   function getData(response) {
      if (response.response) {
         setInfo(response.response);
      } else {
         console.log('there was an error');
      }
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);

      fetch(URL, {})
        .then(resp => ({ getData({response: resp}))
        .catch(error => ({ getData({ error });
   }, []);

   return (
     <>
        {loading ? "Loading" : "Not Loading"}
     </>
   );
}

export default MyComp;
```

Maybe not the best, or prettiest, way... but it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting loading in the useEffect hook. Changing a state causes the app to rerender which also you're infinitely doing in the useEffect. 
So once the app loads useEffect hook runs and changes loading, which again causes the app to re-render and the cycle continues.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComp(props) {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
   const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(loading => !loading);

      const getData = response => {
         if (response) {
            setInfo(response);
         } else {
            console.log('there was an error');
         }
         setLoading(loading => !loading);
      };

      fetch(URL, {})
        .then(resp =>  getData( resp))
        .catch(error =>  getData(error));
   }, []);

   return (
     <>
        {loading ? "Loading" : "Not Loading"}
     </>
   );
}

export default MyComp;
```

Comment: Your solution does not work for me, in fact eslint tells me that `loading is defined in an upper context`...